# Zombie object not removed by remove() method in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, setinterval, backbone-views, zombie-process

I am developing a small web application in backbone.js. In one view I am using setInterval method to provide some animation effect. I am changing the src attribute of an img tag at an interval of 3s by incrementing a variable `index`.

The problem is that when I re-enter the same view, the index variable is incremented in less than 3s. Sometimes it is less than 1s.

Before re-rendering the view I am closing the already existing view  with following code to avoid zombie object.

My router

SearchPage :

```
    function(data) {

    if(!directory.myview){

       directory.myview=new directory.SearchView({model:data}); 

    }
 else{

   directory.myview.close();
       directory.myview=new directory.SearchView({model:data});

   }

   // code to append the rendered view to html page comes here 

}
```

My View

```
directory.SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
render:function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
    return this;
},
close :function()
{       
    this.unbind();
    this.remove();
    delete this.$el; 
    delete this.el;
}
```

});

Comment: Could you show where do you use the `setInterval` method?

Comment: You don't need a `close` function anymore if you're binding events with `listenTo`, `View#remove` will do everything needed since Backbone 0.9.9. However, do you actually stop the `setInterval` method before launching a new one with `clearInterval`? If you're not, there's still a reference to the view you deleted, and that view can't be garbage collected.

Comment: thank you mr. Loamhoof .. i rechecked my code for clearInterval . Problem was there . Reference variable for setInterval  got changed in part of application . So now i set reference variable properly . and working fine

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the sequence in your close is causing the issue. You should remove the view after you delete the ui elements.

```
close :function()
{       
    this.unbind();

    delete this.$el; 
    delete this.el;
    //remove should be last after you delete and unbind
    this.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read [zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) posted by Derick Bailey. It is a great read and once you understand the underlining mechanics, you may want to use [backbone.marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) to manage your views instead.

Comment: This article is out-of-date. The problems he's talking about were fixed by the introduction of the `listenTo` and `stopListening` methods in Backbone 0.9.9. Marionette has since long evolved and don't really serve the purpose of avoiding zombie views anymore.

Comment: Thanks for correcting :-) Through the way the question is posted, thinking that it is valuable to bring the post up:-)